# Is it mandatory to use Redux with React-Native?

Tags: react-native, redux

For some time now, I am learning React-native. I find redux very confusing. It's a completely different way of thinking about your application structure as I come from Java and Angular background.
Any way I was wondering if it is mandatory to use Redux only with react-native? or is it also possible to use some other framework, which is more close to the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Redux and other 'flux-based' patters couple with React/React-Native very well because they follow the same principles (immutability of data, unidirectional flow, etc...). But the final choice is yours. Integrating a different pattern for data management might be a bit tricky (since you'll have to integrate it with the React component lifecycle), but it is definitely possible. In fact, Redux itself needs a binding to React, [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux), since it is not a library *for* React.

In any case, I would advise you not to give up on Redux. It might take a bit of time until everything makes sense in your mind, but after that it is really easy to deal with. If you are having difficulties in any particular topic (actions, reducers...), you can maybe post a new question and we might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer martinarroyo. It makes sense. I shall continue learning Redux :-)